# django-filter looking for templates only in venv

Tags: django-templates, django-filter, django-settings, django-widget

Tried to make custom widget for RangeFilter. Every time django raises

`TemplateDoesNotExist`

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:


django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\django_filters\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Alexander\PycharmProjects\Search\venv\lib\site-packages\bootstrap5\templates\MyRangeWidget.html (Source does not exist)
```

Every path django search for template is in venv. And when i put my widget to match this path, it working just fine.

> venv\lib\site-packages\django_filters\templates\MyRangeWidget.html

But i believe its not correct way to do this.

My widget:

```
<div class="input-group">
{% for widget in widget.subwidgets %}
{% if forloop.first %}
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i></span>
{% endif %}
{% if forloop.last %}
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></span>
{% endif %}


{% include widget.template_name %}
{% endfor %}
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from .models import *
from .widgets import MyRangeWidget


class LandFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = django_filters.RangeFilter(widget=MyRangeWidget)
    size = django_filters.RangeFilter(widget=MyRangeWidget)
    

    class Meta:
        model = PriceChangeHistory
        fields = ['price', 'size']
```

widgets.py

```
import django_filters.widgets


class MyRangeWidget(django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget):
    template_name = 'MyRangeWidget.html'
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'bootstrap5',
    'search',

]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Just to mention, i tried different paths in template_name. Including even absolute path before i notice that django not even try to search for it anywhere except venv.

Have no idea if its me, or its django-filter package problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd day of searching way how to fix it, and right after i ask it here i found the way.

Added django.forms in installed apps and FORM_RENDERER variable like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'django.forms',
    
    'django_filters',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'bootstrap5',
    'search',

]

FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

Now template_name in widget works as expected.